# Create container in Azure storage with c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage

I have the following code:

```
var cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(this._appSettings.BlobConnectionString);
this._cloudBlobClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

CloudBlobContainer container = this._cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("dpd/textures/test");
await container.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
```

I want to create the "test" directory inside dpd/textures/, but I keep getting this error:

> The requested URI does not represent any resource on the server azure
>   container

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just to further clarify Ivan's answer everything in blob storage is a blob, a blob could be of type file or directory for example but as Ivan points out if the "directory" is empty then Azure will automatically delete the empty "directory" blob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is no real directory in blob storage. The directory(not container) is always a part of the blob's name.

So you can just create a container like "dpd", then you can use any upload methods to upload a file like myfile.txt. During uploading file, you can specify your file name as "textures/test/myfile.txt" in your `GetBlockBlobReference` method. Then the directory "textures/test" is created automatically.

Simple code:

```
            CloudBlobClient cloudBlobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference("test1");
            var myblob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("textures/test/myfile.txt");
            myblob.UploadFromFile("your file path");
```

Test result:

[image]

And also note that, if the blob(myfile.txt) is deleted, then the directory "textures/test" will also be removed, since it's a part name of the blob.